# CMake - How to check if string is a file path?

Tags: cmake

I am gathering all license files for the git submodules of my project that are inside a child directory to my project's root directory. From my experience a license file is normally called LICENSE or COPYRIGHT but ultimately I will just add a list of file names to look for.

I am facing a problem with one of the libraries, which has a different name for its license file namely **COPYING** and not **LICENSE** (which will be handled eventually with the list I have mentioned above) but what's more important is that it has a **directory** called **RELICENSES**, which has nothing to do with license files. Needless to say for this dependency my function fails with and error that it's unable to read it (permission denied) as a text file.

Here is my CMake function:

```
# extract_deps_licenses
# For a given directory (root directory for all dependencies) the function will look
# into ONLY the first level of each subdirectory (meaning non-recursive behaviour) and
# look for a license text file. If it finds one, its contents will be read and copyied
# into the provided target license file thus generatng a single license file for all 
# dependencies
# Currently looks for a license file containing the word "LICENSE" (not case-sensitive!)
# Special cases such as a license file not being a text file (e.g. executable) will lead 
# to exiting with error
#
# @param root_dir Root directory for all dependencies
# @param dest_license Path to license file that will be populated
#
# TODO For the future a third argument of type list will be provided. The list will contain
# possible names  for license files incl. COPYING, COPYRIGHT etc.
function(extract_deps_licenses root_dir dest_license)
    message("Retrieving git submodule status for dependencies")
    execute_process(
        COMMAND ${GIT_EXECUTABLE} submodule status
        WORKING_DIRECTORY ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}
        RESULT_VARIABLE deps_git_exit_code
        OUTPUT_VARIABLE deps_git_status
    )

    file(APPEND
        "${dest_license}"
        "\nGit information:\n"
        "\n${deps_git_status}\n"
    )

    # Get all directories under root_dir without recursion (subdirectories will not be traversed)
    file(GLOB dep_dirs "${root_dir}/*" DIRECTORY)
    foreach(dep_dir ${dep_dirs})
        # Get all but the last directory
        string(REGEX MATCH ".*\/" dep_parent_dirs ${dep_dir})
        # Get the last directory by excluding everything else
        # This leaves the dependency directory name, which will be used later
        string(REGEX REPLACE ${dep_parent_dirs} "" dep_name ${dep_dir})
        string(TOUPPER ${dep_name} dep_name)
        message("Found dependency ${dep_name} in \"${dep_dir}\"")

        # Get all items inside 
        file(GLOB paths "${dep_dir}/*")
        message("Looking for license file (non-recursive)")
        foreach(path_license ${paths})
            #get_filename_component(fname ${item} NAME_WE)
            string(TOUPPER "${path_license}" path_up)
            
            # Check if full path contains LICENSE
            # Will not work if LICENSE is a directory!
            string(REGEX MATCH "LICENSE" match ${path_up})

            # Exclude prefixes and suffixes for name of license file
            # directory that has nothing to do with license file)
            # Skip if path does not include LICENSE
            # FIXME Check if match is a file and not directory
            if((NOT match))# OR (NOT path_license FILE)) # <-------------------- CHECK IF A FILE HERE!!!
                continue()
            endif()

            set(license_path ${path_license})
            message("Found license \"${license_path}\"")

            # Read license text and append to full license text
            message("Copying license text to final license file at '${license_path}'")
            file(READ ${license_path} license_content)
            file(APPEND
                "${dest_license}"
                "\n${dep_name}\n\n"
                "${license_content}"
                "\n-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------\n"
            )
        endforeach()
    endforeach()
```

I know the function is not perfect but I am looking into solving the particular problem mentioned in the question - how do I check if a string is a path to a file (not directory!). If I can do that, I can skip a lot of the processing by just dismissing an entry from my list of items found inside the directory  if it's not an file (I will not handle the case where a file LICENSE is weird such as an executable).

Comment: But... why not just `file(GLOB_RECURSE licenses */LICENSE */COPYING)`? `how do I check if a string is a path to a file (not directory!` soo  `if (EXISTS string AND NOT IS_DIRECTORY string)` ?

Comment: See comment to answer from @peter_w

Comment: @KamilCuk There are multiple reasons why I am not globbing like you offer in your comment: case sensitive file names, extracting the dependency's name from each directory where a license file is found and put (along with the license's text) into the destination file etc. I can still do much of this post-globbing but it's more or less the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could call [file(GLOB)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#glob) with the optional `LIST_DIRECTORIES false` parameter:

```cpp
file(GLOB paths LIST_DIRECTORIES false "${dep_dir}/*")
```

Or use [if(IS_DIRECTORY)](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/if.html#file-operations):

```cpp
if((NOT match) OR IS_DIRECTORY "${path_license}")
  continue()
endif()
```

Comment: Ah, the `LIST_DIRECTORIES false` was really nice!

Unless I can use regex as input for globbing somehow doing what you do still forces me to process a lot. The IS_DIRECTORY check (as suggested by @KamilCuk) is what I am looking for. :)

Comment: Strange, when I use `LIST_DIRECTORIES false` I get zero elements in `paths`. I am using CMake 3.21 but set the project to a minimum version 3.12.

Comment: @rbaleksandar I'm sorry, but I can't reproduce this. Using CMake 3.21.2 and a minimum version requirement of 3.12 the `LIST_DIRECTORIES false` works as expected. The only thing I can think of that you need to be cautious about is, that you need to put the `LIST_DIRECTORIES false` _before_ the glob statement(s), otherwise `LIST_DIRECTORIES` and `false` are interpreted as glob statements as well.

Comment: I did what you have suggested and the order is apparently very important.